# Выделение из текста отдельных частей

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

Имею текст: `"mech:type":"Car", "что-то":"ответ на что-то"`

Как мне "отфильтровать" его, т.е. оставить только "Car" и "Ответ на что-то"?

Id у двух TextView: tView1 и tView2

Answer (score 0):

Можно парсить это как JSONObject. Но я пишу как работать просто со строкой, имеющей строго указанную структуру. У меня строка находится в строковых ресурсах.

```
    //ищем границу между первой и второй частями
    String string = getString(R.string.json);
    int index = string.indexOf(",");
    //узнаем информацию о машине
    String carString = string.substring(0, index);
    carString = carString.substring(carString.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    //узнаем ответ на что-то
    String somethingString = string.substring(index + 1);
    somethingString = somethingString.substring(somethingString.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
```

Надеюсь, установить значения для соответствующих текствьюх вы сможете самостоятельно)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через регулярные выражения, например:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(":\"(\\w+|\\W+)\"");
    private static final String TEXT = "\"mech:type\":\"Car\", \"что-то\":\"ответ на что-то\"";

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(TEXT);        
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            results.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println(results);
    }
}
```

Comment: А что если в искомых значениях будут допустимы цифры или знаки препинания?

Comment: Предыдущие решение покрывала цифры, а вот насчет знаков.
Возможно тогда надо условие все символы кроме " и : например :\"([^":]+)\"